# How can I make OAuth2 authentication to the Picasa Web Albums Data API with C#?

Tags: c#, authentication, google-api, restsharp, picasa

I'm trying to upload a photo using the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostPhotos) in C# and I'm using RestSharp to help me with the HTTP requests.

I have the client ID and the client secret, but I don't know how to put that on the http request to make the authentication.

I'm getting the error:

> Modification only allowed with api authentication.

The StatusCode that is returning is `Forbidden`

Here is my code where  is my user ID and  is my album ID.

The method "Authenticantion()" returns a token that I already have.

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostImage(){
    var restclient = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/<userID>/albumid/<albumID>") {Method = Method.POST};

    string imageBase64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";

    request.AddParameter("client_id", this._clientID);
    request.AddParameter("client_secret", this._clientSecret);
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    request.AddHeader("GData-Version", "3");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    request.AddHeader("accessToken", Authenticantion());
    request.AddBody(@"Content-Length: 5951
                      Slug: banana.jpeg " + imageBase64);

    var tResponse = restclient.Execute(request);
    var responseJson = tResponse.Content;
    var token = Authenticantion();

    return responseJson;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth2 authentication normally happens inside a user flow, where the user makes the login with the user and allow (or not) some scopes to the app (e.g. access Picasa, read  only for Google Drive).

You can check the complete flow through this link: [OAuthPlayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). And get your own token at the end of the flow to use with your HTTP requests. One thing to take care is about refresh the tokens, inside the playground it's possible to set to never expire. But on the real world you would need to implement this refresh.

The Picasa API is a little outdated, I'd recommend you to use GoogleDrive instead, it's much more flexible and up to date.
[GoogleDrive_API_Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload)

It's also possible to make this flow via [OAuth2_ Server to server](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), but I never tried before.

Comment: I uset OAuthPlayground to generate a token for Google Drive and made a POST to google drive api. It worked!